# Definability in first order language

Tags: logic, model-theory, first-order-logic

Suppose we have a structure $U$ = ($\mathbb{R}^{+}\cup\{0\}; 0, 1, *)$ where * is multiplication. Equality is also present. What are the definable elements of $U$?

My thoughts:

I think you can define inequality here (although it's not an element of $U$). 
And I also think now that you can only define 0,1.

and on a similar note... is $<$ definable on $(\mathbb{R};0,+)$? I suspect not. I think there is a way to do it in the naturals ($\exists x \in \mathbb{N}(y=z+x 
\wedge x+y \neq y))$ but I don't see how you can do  it in R given the existence of negative numbers. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your second question is more similar than you think, since $(\mathbb{R}^+;1,*)$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{R};0,+)$ via a logarithm.

Comment: Hint on the second part: $f(x) = -x$ is an automorphism of $(\mathbb{R}; 0,+)$ which does not preserve $<$.

Comment: Your question asks about definable *elements*, but then you mention open and closed intervals, which would be definable *sets*. Which are you interested in?

Comment: Hi, yes I made a mistake. It should be definable elements.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: note that $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is an automorphism for each $\alpha\neq 0$. This is enough to answer both questions.

(More generally, if you ignore $0$, it is a divisible, torsion-free abelian group. Those have quantifier elimination, so definable sets are quantifier-free definable. The zero doesn't change the picture much: there are essentially no interactions between it and the rest of the structure.)